# How to store c# imagesource into database ?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

How to store BitmapImage type ImageSource into image type database

Comment: That's a bad practice in most cases. Why don't you store the image path instead?

Comment: are you asking how to store image data on a sql database?

Comment: Store it in the field of `blob` type, if you needed.

Comment: @Raptor Image path isn't useful for the situation. Need to store the image into database. have to convert imagesource into byte[] or some other datatype. but there is no proper way to convert imagesource into byte[] or other. to store the image into "image" datatype also need some conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply Convert it to byte array and define your image in DB as `varbinary(MAX)`
You can use this code:

```
public static Byte[] ConvertToByteFromBitmapImage(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    byte[] data;
    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(ms);
        data = ms.ToArray();
    }

    return data;
}
```

Note: You can use ans simply cast `BitmapImage` as `ImageSource`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream stream = File.OpenRead("<your filePath>");
 var buffer = new byte[stream.Length]; 
 stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int) stream.Length);
```

Now you can save the buffer into column with datatype varbinary(MAX).
It is good if you store them in chunks.

Comment: Much simpler: `var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(...);`